# Android viewHolder CursorAdapter CheckBox not work

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-cursoradapter, android-viewholder

Androd SQLite display data read from a `CursorAdapter` class and a `ListView` in `ViewHolder` instead.

I wanted a `CheckBox` for each line, which can put specific updates the database record.

The thing does not work well because when I activate the first line `CheckBox` you change that appear on the screen last line record.

```
long _id = todo.getID(); //

checkBoxFavorite.setTag(_id);
checkBoxFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) 
    {
        //Update database row
        }
        else if (!isChecked)
        {
        //Update database row
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you add another `if` in  `if (isChecked) {} else if (!isChecked) {}`? while you can just do it with only one `if (isChecked) {} else {}`.

Comment: @Rami why `if` at all if in both branches the same action is taken?

Comment: @pskink readability!

Comment: @Rami what? `if (expr) {do_somethig();} else {do_somethig();}`

Comment: @pskink Yep in this case he don't need the *if* at all, but maybe he's doin' some other stuff other than updating the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private ArrayList<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("e");
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

class TestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    CheckBox checkBox;
    public TestViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        checkBox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    }
    public void addDetail(int positon)
    {
        checkBox.setText(list.get(positon));
    }
}
class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestViewHolder>
{
    public TestAdapter()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public TestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,null);
        return new TestViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TestViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
    {
        viewHolder.addDetail(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the setTag() and getTag(), on the view you can check out from this blog post [Link](http://The%20issue%20with%20CheckBox%20inside%20ListView%20is%20that%20the%20view%20gets%20recycled%20due%20to%20recycling%20of%20ListView%20and%20the%20value%20of%20Checkbox(check%20or%20uncheck)%20is%20not%20maintained.%20To,%20maintain%20the%20state%20to%20CheckBox%20there%20has%20to%20be%20something%20that%20can%20store%20the%20state%20of%20Checkbox.)

This is not a stright forward answer but it will get started.

Comment: getTag() = +9 row. Image: [link](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150902/Screenshot_2015-09-02-09-47-41_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg)